# Learning Causal Graph from data

Tags: causality, graphical-model, bayesian-network, dag

I am quite new to the theory of causal graphs, but from what I understand they are DAG, like Bayesian Networks. Since we have structure learning methods for Bayesian Networks like score based approaches, Chow-Liu Algorithm, etc., can we use these structure learning methods to first learn a Bayesian Network and then estimate the causal effects once we have the Bayesian Network?

Is it is a reasonable approximation to estimate true causal effect by first learning a Bayesian Network using Structural Learning methods and using it as a surrogate causal graph to estimate causal effects? What problems would arise with this approach towards estimating causal effects? And is there any difference between a Causal Graph and a Bayesian Network?